# Interface down until confuguration saved

Tags: pfsense

I've got an interface "WAN1" on a VLAN network port (VLAN 90).

The interface is working fine, but when I reboot pfSense (or when it is automatically rebooted after e.g. a software update), the interface remains down until I manually go into the configuration and hit `Save` (without actually changing anything).

The WAN config isn't fancy: just DHCP IPv4 only (VLAN 90 is directly connected to a Cable Modem (no NAT).

```
Cable modem (without NAT) -- Switch (VLAN 90) -- pfSense IF using VLAN 90
```

What am I doing wrong? Anything I can do to debug?

EDIT as requested by comments, here's the output of /tmp/:

```
[2.3.2-RELEASE][root@diocles.tersig.local]/tmp: ls -lah
total 192
drwxrwxrwt   3 root  wheel   1.0K Aug  5 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel   1.0K Aug  5 16:32 ..
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:33 DDNS0.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:33 DDNS1.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:00 PHP_errors.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:33 bootup_messages
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    39K Aug  5 18:43 config.cache
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 18:55 config.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   469B Aug  5 18:43 dhcpd.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 em1_vlan90_error_output
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   150B Aug  5 17:10 em1_vlan90_output
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    12B Aug  5 17:10 em1_vlan90_router
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 18:43 filter.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:33 ipsec.lock
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   512B Aug  5 16:32 mnt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1.7K Aug  5 18:54 pfctl_si_out
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    68K Aug  5 18:54 pfctl_ss_out
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:32 php_errors.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    10B Aug  5 17:10 pppoe0_defaultgw
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 pppoe0_defaultgwv6
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    17B Aug  5 16:33 pppoe0_ip
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    11B Aug  5 16:33 pppoe0_router
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 16:33 pppoe0up
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 rclinkupem1.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 rclinkupem1_vlan20.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 rclinkupem1_vlan50.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 rclinkupem1_vlan90.lock
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 17:10 resolvconf.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    13K Aug  5 18:43 rules.debug
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    13K Aug  5 18:43 rules.debug.old
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   105B Aug  5 18:43 rules.limits
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   161B Aug  5 18:55 sess_p81jg17t684tt414j8d646ij4852
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug  5 18:53 tmpHOSTS
[2.3.2-RELEASE][root@diocles.tersig.local]/tmp:
```

Not much there unfortunately: `em1_vlan90_error_output` is an empty file, same for `bootup_messages`.

Comment: Have a look in `/tmp/bootup_messages` logs as well as any error logs in that directory.

Comment: @BittenFleax: the file is empty. Logs that do have content don't indicate much.